# Help, can not install cURL

Tags: 14.04, curl

I'm not able to install cURL, the command

```
sudo apt-get install curl libcurl3 libcurl3-dev php5-curl
```

shows

```
packages ... 0%
```

and nothing else happens.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question ([edit]). You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 0):

1. First install CURL by typing `sudo apt install curl`
2. Then Restart Apache by typing `sudo service apache2 restart`
3. Then install PHP5 CURL by typing `sudo apt install php5-curl`
4. Then Restart Apache by typing`sudo service apache2 restart`

Link: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/curl-is-not-installed-in-your-php-installation